# How to replace a string present in file A and the first column of file B and replace by corresponding string in the second column of file B?

Tags: string, replace, gff

*File A (tab-delimited, 10 columns):*

> chrI  DBVPG6765   gene    7249    9030    .   -   .   ID=01G00030;Name=**YAL067W**
> chrI   DBVPG6765   mRNA    7249    9030    .   -   .   ID=01T00030.1;Parent=01G00030
> chrI  DBVPG6765   exon    7249    9030    .   -   .   ID=01T00030.1.exon.1;Parent=01T00030.1
> chrI DBVPG6765   CDS 7249    9030    .   -   .   ID=01T00030.1.CDS.1;Parent=01T00030.1
> chrI  DBVPG6765   gene    11586   11945   .   -   .   ID=01G00040;Name=**YAL065C**
> chrI   DBVPG6765   mRNA    11586   11945   .   -   .   ID=01T00040.1;Parent=01G00040
> chrI  DBVPG6765   exon    11586   11945   .   -   .   ID=01T00040.1.exon.1;Parent=01T00040.1
> chrI DBVPG6765   CDS 11586   11945   .   -   .   ID=01T00040.1.CDS.1;Parent=01T00040.1

*File B (tab-delimited, 2 columns):*

YAL001C TFC3
YAL002W    VPS8
YAL003W    EFB1
YAL005C    SSA1
YAL007C    ERP2
YAL008W    FUN14
YAL009W   SPO7 
YAL010C   MDM10
YAL011W   SWC3
YAL012W    CYS3
YAL013W    DEP1
...
YAL067W    SEO1
YAL066W    YAL066W
YAL065C     YAL065C
...

*The format I should get is:*

> chrI   DBVPG6765   gene    7249    9030    .   -   .   ID=01G00030;Name=**SEO1**
> chrI  DBVPG6765   mRNA    7249    9030    .   -   .   ID=01T00030.1;Parent=01G00030
> chrI  DBVPG6765   exon    7249    9030    .   -   .   ID=01T00030.1.exon.1;Parent=01T00030.1
> chrI DBVPG6765   CDS 7249    9030    .   -   .   ID=01T00030.1.CDS.1;Parent=01T00030.1
> chrI  DBVPG6765   gene    11586   11945   .   -   .   ID=01G00040;Name=**YAL065C**
> chrI   DBVPG6765   mRNA    11586   11945   .   -   .   ID=01T00040.1;Parent=01G00040
> chrI  DBVPG6765   exon    11586   11945   .   -   .   ID=01T00040.1.exon.1;Parent=01T00040.1
> chrI DBVPG6765   CDS 11586   11945   .   -   .   ID=01T00040.1.CDS.1;Parent=01T00040.1

---

ID=DBVPG6765_01G00030;Name=YAL067C is column 10 in file A. The script/ one-liner should look for YAL067W in file B and replace YALO67W with the corresponding second column of file B (SEO1 in this case).

Since the order of genes in file B is not identical to the line number in file A, awk 'NR==FNR ... is not working.

Anyone has some advice or a small script of how I should proceed with this?
I should mention I'm quite new to scripting/programming.

Comment: can you improve the formatting of you question.

Comment: @antzshrek is this format better?